# arduino serial comminucation

Tags: arduino-uno

my vb.net app produce this result as 2d array :

01110000000111000

01110000000111000

01110000000000000

01110111000111000

01111111100111000

01110011100111000

01110011100111000

01110011100111000

01110011100111000

01110011100111000

00000000000000000

i want to send every single column to my arduino over serial port and use the column to turn on this leds : 
* leds connected from pin 2 to pin 13
 [image: arduino uno r3]

anyone can help me ? :(

Comment: And what have you tried so far? What part of it are you having problems with?

Comment: the problem is how to send array over serial port and recieve it in arduino  ? i've no idea how to do that :|   

*i am new with arduino.

Comment: So basically everything then?  We can't help you with the VB side of things - try [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) for that. For the Arduino side of things, this may help: http://hacking.majenko.co.uk/reading-serial-on-the-arduino

Comment: I don't see resistors in your LED circuits.  You run the risk of damaging your Uno if you drive LEDs without series resistors to limit current.  Eg 330Ω for 10 mA, 3300Ω for 1 mA, etc.